# Raytracer output very noisy image

Tags: c++, rendering, raytracing

I'm following "Raytracer the next week" minbook Chapter 6, and after adding light to the my scene the ray tracer output those very noisy images, i tried to increase the samples to and depth number and still getting those issues but refined.

I want to understand why i got those patterns.

[image: Sphere in the middle emitting light]
here the sphere in the middle is the light source "emit material"

[image: 2 Rectangles with diffuselight materials in top]
Here the top 2 rectangles are the light sources "Emit material"

Comment: You don't even dare to mention what chapter of the book you are targetting atm. So even the 0.001% of SO people who happen to have read that book will not be able to help you.

Comment: @sebrockm Sorry for that, "chapter 6" which cover lighting, and i edit the post with my code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, it turns out that the problem was with my random number generation code.

I was using this this statement `rand()%10/10.0f` which return only floating point number between [0.0, 1.0[ which is very low resolution and then i replace it with `rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)`  and it's fine now.

If any one has a better solution for high resolution random generation in C++ please let drop a comment.

Comment: Avoid integer division, due to its rounding. Prefer `float(rand()) / RAND_MAX`

Comment: I was puzzling over this one.  I've written a few small project raytracers, and hadn't come across this situation before. I'm glad you figured out the problem, and now in hindsight the problem's cause makes sense.  :-)